# Android Automotive emulator error: The process for AVD has terminated

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-automotive

I can't run Automotive (not Auto) emulator.

I tried different images for configuring it. Every time I configure virtual device, its created with just 1MB size.

When I create any other phone or tablet virtual devices, there size is bigger than 500 MB. On start I get error: "The process for AVD  has terminated".

The difference in file structure of normal virtual device and automotive virtual device is that automotive doesn't have file `sdcard.img`

Here is a record in idea.log file:
`Emulator: Automotive (1024p landscape) API 32 - Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)`

There are 37 GB of free space on the disk

**I will be grateful for any help**

UPD:

Tried on:

- Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 1
- Android Studio Hedgehog | 2023.1.1 Canary 4

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to add system image first (https://developer.android.com/training/cars/testing#system-images).

Also, please make sure to use Android Studio Canary version. As of now, only canary version supports Android Automotive system images.

Comment: I use Android Studio Hedgehog, and followed all the steps on that link. Also virtual device wouldn’t get created without image

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the installation of location of the SDK was not in the expected place.

I will put here the steps I've done on a MacBook to debug the issue.

1. Go to SDK tools

   cd ~/Library/Android/sdk/tools
2. Turn on the emulator

   emulator -avd *emulator_name*
3. Check the error, in my case it was:

   **PANIC: Cannot find AVD system path. Please define ANDROID_SDK_ROOT**

So the SDK was not found.

From here, what I've done was to check the **config.init** file of the emulator (can be found in Users/*your_user*/.android/avd/*emulator_name*).

There is a line where the system image directory is defined:

image.sysdir.1=system-images/android-32/android-automotive-playstore/arm64-v8a/

In my case, at that location, the system image was not present.
I found it installed in other place, copied to Users/*my_user*/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-32 as defined in config.init and now the emulator works :)

[image]